# Problem with uploading and saving an image in Django

Tags: django, django-views

*(13, 'Permission denied')* error occurs when trying to upload an image in Django 
i have checked the access rights of the directory in which image will be saved 
drwxr-xr-x  2 hsrd hsrd    4096 2010-03-19 15:49 media

Please a suggest a solution for this.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'file' in request.FILES:
            file = request.FILES["file"]
            fdata = file.read(file.size)
            b = base64.b64encode(fdata)
            from StringIO import StringIO
    content=StringIO(fdata)
    upload_dir = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
            destination =os.path.join(upload_dir, image_name)
    from PIL import Image
        img = Image.open(content)
    image_to_scratch(img,destination)

            return render_to_response('ocr/ocr.html',{
                    'filename':file.name,
                    'hasImage':True,
                    'imgdata':r'data:image/png;base64,' + b

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isnt formatted too well, so i havent read that, but I would recommend checking which user the django instance is running as, if you are deploying with mod_wsgi check out:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess

Comment: I am not using mod_wsgi.i tried it with modpython as described in the tutorial http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/?from=olddocs

Comment: Solved the problem changed the filepath in which image to saved to /tmp

Comment: im glad you have solved the problem, but if the images are to be stored permanently /tmp is not the place for them to go!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the user Django is running under is not 'hsrd'.
You can:

- Run Django under the 'hsrd' user (may not be feasible)
- CHOWN the directory so it belongs to the user Django is running under
- (Easiest) Chmod 775 the directory

Comment: Thnaks for the answer. I have already tried the 3rd option.Still its not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at @agos is correct, and that you're running this as the "apache" or "httpd" user, a solution that will be reasonably effective is to change the ownership of the directory to the same user that's running the Apache/Modpython processes.

```
chown -R apache:apache fully_quality_dir_path
```

should do the trick. Make sure you get the media_root directory and everything underneath it, at least based on your code snippet above.